# stacking issue with items in overflow z-index and flex container

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have two sections stacked on top of each other as follows as can be seen in this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xnqt4aup/3/).

I want the dropdown to appear over the bottom section, however, setting the `z-index` is having no effect. Also, I am aware I can update `.card` to also be `position: absolute` and it will work, however this breaks my whole layout so isn't really an option.

Does anyone know how I can make the dropdown appear over the bottom section without changing the `.card` class to `position: absolute`?

```css
h3, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  /* uncomment line below to see how the dropdown should look */
  /* position: absolute; */
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.row-two {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-one"> 
      <h3>Top Section</h3>
      <div class='card'>
        <p>I'm a card</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <h1>DROPDOWN</h1>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-two">
    <h3>Bottom Section</h3>
    <p>...content</p>
    <p>...content</p>
    <p>...content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: remove the `overflow-y: auto;` ?

Comment: Is there a reason why you use the overflow-y: auto om the .row-one element? If not, what @TemaniAfif said is the cleanest and simplest fix.

Comment: @TemaniAfif oh sorry, I need that too, unless there is an alternative. If I remove that in my real code it cause all the other items to show below the bottom section. I hope that makes sense

Comment: Then @l0w_skilled's answer is the way to go.

Comment: @guitarzero ahhh, I don't think that works for me as my html is a bit more complicated than the example I have provided :-(

Comment: keep position:absolute and move the element using top

Answer (score 3):

As the `card` has `position: relative` the absolute positioned children inside are bound to it (This applies to the z-index also). You can put the `position: relative` on the `wrapper`.

```css
h3, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  /* add positon relative */
  position:relative;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

.card {
  /* remove position relative */
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50px;
  left: 0;
}

.row-two {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-one"> 
      <h3>Top Section</h3>
      <div class='card'>
        <p>I'm a card</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <h1>DROPDOWN</h1>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
        </div>
      </div>
  </div>

  <div class="row-two">
    <h3>Bottom Section</h3>
    <p>...content</p>
    <p>...content</p>
    <p>...content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks for this. unfortunately it doesnt work and also I think I need the card to be `position: relative`. Perhaps what I want to do is impossible?

Comment: Then you have to move the dropdown out of the card.

Comment: yeah, I have tried that. I will try again, but that kind of makes a mess of my layout too. That could be the answer though, thanks

Comment: only thing is if I put `position: relative` at any stage it seems to break

Answer (score -1):

`z-index` won't work with statically positioned elements. You at least need to have a `position: relative;` on `.dropdown` for `z-index` to work on it. Also I don't think you need the `overflow-y: auto;` on `.row-one`, it should rather `overflow-y: visible;`. Here's my take on it.

Link to jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/gh5ne2or/

```css
h3, p {
  margin: 0;
}

.wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.row-one {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex: 0 1 200px;
  background: red;
  overflow-y: visible;
}

.card {
  position: relative;
  /* uncomment line below to see how the dropdown should look */
  /* position: absolute; */
  background: orange;
  width: 200px;
  height: 100px;
}

.dropdown {
  height: 300px;
  width: 200px;
  background: blue;
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}

.row-two {
  flex: 1;
  display: flex;
  background: #fff;
  flex-direction: column;
  background: pink;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="row-one">

      <h3>Top Section</h3>
      <div class='card'>
        <p>I'm a card</p>
        <div class="dropdown">
          <h1>DROPDOWN</h1>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
          <p>item</p>
        </div>
      </div>
     
  </div>

  <div class="row-two">
    <h3>Bottom Section</h3>
    <p>...content</p>
    <p>...content</p>
    <p>...content</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Dropdown is not static. Take a look again. It's positioned absolute.

Comment: thanks for your answer. The other thing is the way it is set up currently I need the `overflow-y" auto`

Comment: @peterflanagan, does this work for you? Without `overflow-y: auto` though, you are going to get scrolling on `.row-one`.

Comment: exactly, that is the reason I need overflow-y